# SQL Selecting only the occurrences of a number twice

Tags: sql

I have a database that I am querying against phone numbers. I want to find the phone numbers that have a number only occur twice.

For example I want to find all phone numbers that only have the number 3 occur twice like

(222) 344-9834

as opposed to

(222) 344-9833

I am using a like and my query is below

```
Select SupplierID, Phone
from Suppliers
where  Phone Like '%3%3'
```

Which is not quite the query results I am expecting, due to the fact I meet the criteria and get results with more than two 5's. How can I do this? Would I be better using a Not Like?

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is `like` and `not like`:

```
Select SupplierID, Phone
from Suppliers
where Phone Like '%3%3%' and Phone not like '%3%3%3%';
```

Comment: I did not know you could use both statements, thank you for the insight